# Составить регулярное выражение для поиска "18 августа"

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Не получается правильно составить регулярное выражение для поиска "18 августа". Думаю, что необходимо  найти две цифры, за которыми идёт пробел, а следом — семь кириллических букв. Количество цифр и букв задать квантификатором {}

```js
const regExp = /шаблон/; // напишите регулярное выражение, которое ищет число и месяц

const aelita = '"Инженер М.С. Лось приглашает желающих лететь с ним 18 августа на планету Марс явиться для личных переговоров от 6 до 8 вечера. Ждановская набережная, дом 11, во дворе".';

console.log(aelita.match(regExp)); //["18 августа"]
```

Comment: Но вы так и "17 февраля" найдете.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ТС'у именно это и необходимо

Comment: По поводу вопроса: необходимо найти 1 или 2 цифры, за которыми идёт пробел, и далее 3-7 кириллических  символов.

Comment: @694201970 А почему 3-7? Чем не угодил сентябрь?

Comment: @Yaant, точно. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const re = /[\d]+\s+(?:январ|феврал|март|апрел|ма|июн|июл|август|сентябр|октябр|ноябр|декабр)[аяйь\s]/i;
const str = 'Инженер М.С. Лось приглашает желающих лететь с ним 18 августа на планету Марс явиться для личных переговоров от 6 до 8 вечера. Ждановская набережная, дом 11, во дворе';
console.log(str.match(re));
```

**UPD** регулярное выражение можно уточнить, за счёт указания диапазона чисел от 1 до 31: `([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` Спасибо @teran

Comment: `\d` уж вы упростили сильно. должен интересовать диапазон 1-31 а не любые числа. Условно что-то такое https://regex101.com/r/UUojtW/1

Comment: @teran, Согласен

Comment: `[аяйь\s]` лучше, наверное, заменить на `[аяйь](?![а-яё])`, чтобы не срабатывало на чём-то вроде «25 маяков»

Comment: искал решение с использованием квантификатора, кажется /\d{2}\s[а-я]{7}/ подойдет

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = '"Инженер М.С. Лось приглашает желающих лететь с ним 18 августа на планету Марс явиться для личных переговоров от 6 до 8 вечера. Ждановская набережная, дом 11, во дворе".';

const matches = text.match(/([0-9]+\s[А-я]{7})/g);

console.log(matches); //["18 августа"]
```